# How do you pronounce dado?

Tags: terminology, dado

When perusing woodworking articles online, I often read about dado joints made with dado cuts using dado blades.

[image: Outline of a two wooden planks showcasing two types of dado cuts]

<sup>SilentC at the English language Wikipedia [GFDL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html) or [CC-BY-SA-3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), via Wikimedia Commons</sup>

Each time I come across the word *dado*, I pronounce it differently and it's starting to bug me. Which is the correct way to pronounce *dado*? Is it:

- dado like dad
- dado like dot
- dado like date

Comment: I like using [Google for that](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Adado). (Click on the little speaker next to the pronunciation notation.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[noun da·do \ˈdā-(ˌ)dō](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dado)

It's pronounced with both a long 'a' as in day and a long 'o' as in oh. Primary emphasis (indicated by ') is on the first syllable.

Answer (score 5):

I've always heard it pronounced "Day-dough"